# Accessing BundleContext with Felix dependency manager

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, felix-dependency-manager

I am using Apache Felix dependency manager in my project. In the service activation method

```
@org.apache.felix.dm.annotation.api.Start
public void activate() {
// Need BundleContext here
}
```

I need an access to BundleContext or Bundle. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a volatile BundleContext field in your class and the dependency manager will inject it.

Comment: Tried it but it did not work. The context in star() method was null :(

Comment: As a work around I am using FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass());

Comment: I don't use annotations but `private volatile BundleContext bundleContext;` works for me.

Comment: When using annotations you need to add a @Inject annotation